# How to print paypal return arrays

Tags: php, arrays, paypal

I am using Martin Maly's [Paypal Library](http://mmaly.net/paypal-library/) and everything works properly.The thing I could not manage to do is I get something like this in the returning page;

```
   Array
(
    [TOKEN] => EC-49D73912N5410881H
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2011-11-24T10:59:46Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 328dc8f80aac
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 52.0
    [BUILD] => 2271164
    [EMAIL] => hello_1321870042_per@blablabla.com
    [PAYERID] => QZNN94QVUSL88
    [PAYERSTATUS] => verified
    [FIRSTNAME] => Test
    [LASTNAME] => User
    [COUNTRYCODE] => FR
    [CUSTOM] => 20|EUR|
)
```

And I want all these data to be printed seperately such as;

```
echo $array['EMAIL'];
```

This is the first time I work with arrays and I have no idea how to deal with it?
I would be very glad if anyone out here help me.
Thanks.

Comment: `echo $array['EMAIL'];` should work fine, as long as `$array` is the name of the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either do:

```
print_r($array);
```

or if you want it more readable:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
```

or this if you want to output some array values but not others:

```
$output_these_keys = array('FIRSTNAME', 'LASTNAME', 'CUSTOM');
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($key, $output_these_keys)) echo "$key: $value\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much the last example made my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to access and print array keys and array values separately? Here you go:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  echo $key . ": " . $value;
}
```

Also, if you want to drop the keys and instead have indexed array starting from 0 (that is, being able to access array with indexes), use `array_values($array);` which will return indexed array

And don't be afraid of really helpful official [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).